# Inkscape - Ungroup and Break Apart vie Inkscape CLI

Tags: inkscape, svg, dxf

I am relatively new to this topics. I am trying to covert my svg file into dxf. This can be done with GUI and works fine but I have a lot of such small files which are needed to be converted to dxf so I wanted to automate this. Can anyone suggest me or tell me if such commands exist?

It can be CLI or even any programming tool/API/Script

Thanks

Comment: Which operating system? Are they all in the same (sub-?)directory and do you want to convert all of them? I'm still on Xubuntu 18.04 and the manpage for inkscape doesn't mention a possibility to convert to dxf. Image Magic's convert command has some issues too, but that were the first two ideas which came to my mind, for unix like systems probably in combination with a for-loop or a find-command.